# What's the subject of 'mind not so much to know' ? (1670 UK, Isaac Penington)

Tags: early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

[Source:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3012/8712) Para 5, [Isaac Penington to Widow Hemmings (1670)](http://www.qhpress.org/texts/penington/letter45.html), by [Isaac Penington](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Penington_%28Quaker%29)

> The Lord so guide thee, manifest himself to thee, help thee, and lead
>   thee by his Holy Spirit and power, as that thou mayst come undeniably
>   to experience, and to be satisfied by him about these things. And **mind**
>   not so much to know, as to be obedient <445> [sic] and subjected to the
>   Lord, both in thy heart and in thy conversation also, in `the least thing that he makes manifest`.

1. What's the subject of the verb **mind**? How do you determine/deduce this?

2. Does this para reveal what is `the least > thing that he makes manifest`?

Comment: It's the "*pay attention*" sense, as in "*mind the gap!*" or "*pay him no mind*" or "*mind your manners*", etc. You determine/deduce this by recognizing there are only a finite number of established meanings for "*mind*", and that's the only one which fits in this context, as well as having a broad enough exposure to English to recognize it there. The "*least thing he makes manifest*" is not a specific entity, but an extension of the admonishment to *pay attention* to God, and even the smallest detail he reveals to you.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you! I remember your preference for comments but wanted to express my thanks.

Comment: No problem @Law (by the way, given the nature of your inquiry, I might have more clearly expressed the sense as "*regard X as important*", rather than "*pay attention to*").

Comment: It _could_ be an imperative. But it _could_ be a sentence fragment continuing the list after '... thou mayst come undeniably to' (where a comma would be less ambiguous, but give a heavy sentence).

Answer (score 2):

The implied subject of the ***imperative*** *[mind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mind?searchDictCode=all)* would be *thou*.

> VERB
>
> 3.3 [IN IMPERATIVE] Be careful about the quality or nature of:

The phrase, *in the least thing that he makes manifest*, modifies the compound object of the infinitive phrase: *to be obedient and and subject*. A decent modern paraphrase becomes:

> "Be careful ... to be obedient ... in *every detail* of what he *shows you*."

Some would point out, with a **degree** of merit, Penington's earlier statement:

> The Lord...manifest **himself** to thee ... and lead thee ... to
>   experience, and to be satisfied by **him**...

It is not conclusive by any means, but a legitimate theory is that G-d himself is what is being manifest to Pennington's students, implying the paraphrase:

> "Be careful ... to be obedient ... in *every detail* of *G-d*."

Regardless, the ***details*** of what might be manifest are not revealed in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

1. thou (you).  That is generally the understood subject of an imperative in English.
2. No.